# Prompt for parameters with SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I really like the SQL tools within Visual Studio and very rarely use SQL Server Management Studio.  I'm updating queries written by another developer and he used SQL Management Studio.  For some reason Visual Studio is formatting the query, which makes it hard to work with.

A few of the queries have parameters in them and when I run the query in Management Studio I'm getting an error.  In Visual Studio I'm used to it prompting me for the parameters.  Is there a way I can tell Management Studio to prompt me for those values?

Comment: Could you please explain me how have you used the parameters in Visual Studio? I can't manage to get the prompt neither in VS nor SSMS by any means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS will prompt for parameters for a stored procedure, if you right click the proc and select "EXECUTE".  Otherwise, no, it will not prompt for parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template syntax, to be prompted for the values before execution, by clicking the "Specify Values for Template Parameters" in the toolbar.

```
<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
```

[image]