# Using @startdate and @enddate in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prompt for parameters with SQL Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125238/prompt-for-parameters-with-sql-management-studio)

I have a query where i use @startdate and @enddate in the sql and if I run this on a colleagues PC he gets prompted to choose values for each field, I do not however on mine.

Is there a setting in sql management studio that I need to turn on to get it to show the pop up window when I run this sql?

Thanks

Comment: Is your colleague using Visual Studio?

Comment: no same management console as me

Comment: Can you show the query? Is it an SP ?