# Get Dynamic Values in SQL Query in SSMS 2014

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have some queries that I run often, and just change the values for. In a past life, I know I was able to create queries that would prompt for the values. But, I cannot recall the syntax or figure out how to do it in SSMS2014.

Something like: SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Table_Name WHERE Column_Name = '& userInput'

Comment: Access have this functionality, ssms doesn't have. However you can refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125238/prompt-for-parameters-with-sql-management-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Template Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230912.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM <Table Name, sysname, Table_Name>
WHERE <Column Name, sysname, Column_Name> = '<Value, varchar(20), 42>'
```

Template parameters take the form:

```
<parameter_name, data_type, default_value>
```

Use the "Specify values for template parameters" option (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+M</kbd>) on the Query menu to bring up a dialog where you can enter the values.

Comment: Thanks! That will help. I think the short answer is "no" this isn't natively available in SSMS.

I had determined that the functionality I used previously was in SQL Developer.